# Dictionary: recursive check for each key/value and replace

Tags: python

I have a complex python dictionary with multiple nested keys and nested dictionaries. Some of those are in `datetime` format and i need to convert those to unix epoch (conversion is not a problem)

Example:

```
{
   "maybetime": datetime(),
   "other:" 12,
   "other2:" "xxx",
   "nested": {
      "maybetime": datetime(),
      "other": 12,
      "other2": "xxx",
      "other3": datetime()
   }
}
```

I want to get:

```
{
   "maybetime": 13213213213,
   "other:" 12,
   "other2:" "xxx",
   "nested": {
      "maybetime": 3213213213,
      "other": 12,
      "other2": "xxx",
      "other3": 3213213213
   }
}
```

How to check effectively recursively every key in nested `dict` and replace it if needed?

Comment: nesting is only 1 level deep, so just iterate over all values' values and do your conversion (which you said isn't a problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def recursively_iterate(d: dict):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            recursively_iterate(v)
        elif isinstance(v, datetime.datetime):
            v = convert_datetime_to_unix_time()    # update here
            d[k] = v
```

You need to iterate on the entire dictionary, recursively (or using a stack) and whenever you find a datetime object, convert it to unix epoch and replace it in-place.